# Update a entity in preupdate event using doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine

I am working on the doctrine 2.

Issue:
  I am going to update the entity Order, at the same time i need to update the Website Entity also. So i have created a EventListener for order and implemented a method preUpdate() to updating a Website.

My code:

```
public function preUpdate($eventArgs) {
    $order = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('contactId')) {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $website = $order->getWebsite();
        $website->setContactId($order->getContactId());
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
                $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($website)), $website);
    }
}
```

But it will through the following error: Class \Website is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Kindly suggest how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the Website entity we need to add this entity into the compute change set.

```
public function preUpdate($eventArgs) {
    $order = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('contactId')) {
        $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $website = $order->getWebsite();
        $website->setContactId($order->getContactId());
        $uow->computeChangeSet(
                $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($website)), $website);
    }
}
```